# Json deserialize issue with tuple

Tags: c#, json, silverlight, windows-phone-8, deserialization

I created a silverlight project for Windows Phone 8 a tuple list with an GeoCoordinate and a short value inside.
For doing so I created a TupleList class:

```
public class TupleList<T1, T2> : List<Tuple<T1, T2>>
{
    public void Add(T1 item, T2 item2)
    {
        Add(new Tuple<T1, T2>(item, item2));
    }
}
```

and so I am able to create my tuple like this:

```
new Tuple<GeoCoordinate, short> TupleName;
```

In next step I want to write in in a txt/json file and this works also fine:

```
string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TupleName);
...
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json.ToCharArray());
```

but now my problem is to load this file again and deserialize it again and i am searching for a solution:

```
string TestString = streamReader.ReadLine();
Tuple<GeoCoordinate, short> TestTuple;
TestTuple = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tuple<GeoCoordinate, short>>(TestString);
ListBox_WayPoints.Items.Add(TestTuple);
```

Until the `ReadLine()` it is working just as expected and I get a string like `"Item1: 'GeoCoordinate stuff', Item2: 'short value'"` but the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tuple<GeoCoordinate, short>>` method is always crashing and I don't know why because the debugger is just jumping to a Debugger Breakpoint and the whole Error Message is:

```
Ausnahme ausgelöst: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException" in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
Ausnahme ausgelöst: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException" in mscorlib.ni.dll
```

So I am searching now for examples/help with this issue (unfortunately i wasn't successful yet) how it is possible to deserialize the string correctly.

Comment: Put a try/catch around the the block of code that calls `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Put it around the whole four lines of that block that you quoted in your question. Put a breakpoint in the `catch`, and see what the exception's `Message` property is. That's the error message. It will help you understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after 2 hours I found the answer :D

the whole issue is that i expected a Tuple BUT what i got was a already a TupleList so the whole magic is:

```
string TestString = streamReader.ReadLine();
NewRoute = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TupleList<GeoCoordinate, short>>(TestString);
```